# EF Core 3.1 to 5 Update -> IEntityType.GetTableName

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

In EF Core 3.1 this was working

```
// Model
builder.Entity<MyEntity>().HasNoKey().ToView("MyView", "dbo");

// Then I have this Function
public static GetTableName<T>(this MyDbContext db)
{
      var t = db.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
      return t.GetTableName()
}
```

In EF Core 5 `t.GetTableName()` returns `null` because the method supposed to be used is `t.GetViewName()`

so I changed my code to

`return t.GetTableName() ?? t.GetViewName()`

However I think its "ugly" and I would rather check if `t` is a view or a table and then call the right `t.Get[View/Tabe]Name`. But I didn't find any property or method on `t` itself to find out what it is.

Any Ideas and how to find out if it's a view or a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even Entity Framework Core [source is using the `GetViewName()` method to figure out if an object is a view](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/da00fb69d615fa22a83dfee2077ad31b7bd15823/src/EFCore.Design/Scaffolding/Internal/CSharpEntityTypeGenerator.cs#L167).

With that in mind, I think your solution is concise and you could make your own extension method that does exactly what you have there to hide the "uglyness":

```cs
public static string GetTableOrViewName(this IEntityType entityType) =>
    entityType.GetTableName() ?? entityType.GetViewName();
```

Comment: What's good enough for Microsoft is good enough for me too ;-)